# how do i randomly select a word from an input (python)

Tags: python

I want the user to input a sentence, then randomly select a word in that sentence and print it. I do not know how to do this, any help?
I can only select one letter from the sentence so far.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: `split` the input on whitespace creating a list and the select a random element from the list using `choice` from `random`

Comment: The reason you're getting so many downvotes is because [Stackoverflow's Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) expect you to provide code to demonstrate what you've tried and that you've already looked for ways to solve the answer on your own. You've gotten an answer already, but I wanted to let you know for next time. Stackoverflow respects people who show that they've tried.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically need to do is: 
prompt for input, split into single words and then choose a random word with the help of the [random library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

```
import random

inp = input("Input: ") # prompt for input
# With an example:
# Input: This is a sentence
# produces the string inp="This is a sentence"
list_input = inp.split() # split up the sentence into a list of words
# In our example: 
# list_input = ["This","is","a","sentence"]

print(random.choice(list_input)) # choose a random item from the list of words
# In our example the print statement would choose randomly one of the four words
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the thing you want, just like the answer above, but if you wish you can use this one.

```
import random
sentence = input("Your sentence: ")
words = sentence.split()
words = random.shuffle(words)
yourword = words[0] # or, for more spoiled variation use: 
#yourword = words[random.randint(range(len(words)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#in this code we took the input as a list to make it easier taking each word of the sentence alone  
import sys , random 
sentence=sys.argv[1:]
r=random.choice(sentence)
print(r)
```